# Existence criteria for the LU decomposition of a tridiagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In [this link](http://faculty.washington.edu/finlayso/ebook/algebraic/advanced/LUtri.htm), the following result is presented without proof:

Let $a, b, c$ be the lower off diagonal, diagonal, and upper off diagonal elements of a tridiagonal matrix.  A pivotless LU decomposition exists if $|a_i| + |c_i| < |b_i|$.

I'm trying to convince myself that this is true (so I don't necessarily need a formal proof), but I'm not sure where to start.  Or are there better existence criteria for LU decompositions on tridiagonal matrices?